# Complex dynamic height overflow auto layout

Tags: html, css, height

I'm sure there is a simple solution for this, but I might have just been looking for it for so long that I'm overthinking everything.

Please see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fusiw

I have an absolutely positioned div on my page (for simplicity, it's 0 from all edges in the codepen). Inside, there are three main elements:

- a header, which can be of any height depending on content, and should always be fixed to the top of the parent;
- a footer, which, thankfully, has a fixed height, and should always be fixed to the bottom of the parent;
- and a middle area, which can have any amount of content, should span from the end of the header to the start of the footer, and is supposed to scroll if needed.

My problem is getting the middle area to always begin from the end of the header, and end before the footer. It's supposed to exactly fit whatever height is left between the header and footer.

I don't want scrollbars appearing anywhere else than on the middle area itself. My current solution is working in the sense that only the middle area scrolls, but because I am using `height: 100%` for it, the height of the header is added to it, which shouldn't happen.

Comment: The simplest solution may be to use a table (!?!), otherwise perhaps try display:table, display:table-row etc on your elements.

Comment: @Ted Not a good idea. [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) is applicable to *non-replaced block-level elements and non-replaced inline-block elements*. It won't work on tables (or CSS tables) as they're **replaced elements**.

Comment: Noted--It would provide the scaffolding for the elements--not be the elements, so to speak.

Comment: I'm afraid that you probably need to use a fixed height for the header or to use JavaScript to offset the middle area.

Comment: Still looking for a solution for this?

Comment: @tasseKATT I'd still be happy to hear of some obscure css magic for this, but for now I have gone with javascript :)